# how to convert json in POST to javaBean

Tags: java, json

here is my provider:

```
class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"
```

here is my javaBean

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName("issue")
public class TestBean {

    @JsonProperty("project_id")
    private Integer projectId;

    @JsonProperty("subject")
    private String subject;

    public Integer getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

}
```

here is my service

```
 @WebService
    public class IssueRestfulApi {

          @POST
          @Path("/create")
          @Consumes(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
          public void createIssue(TestBean bean) {
                System.out.println(bean.getSubject());
                System.out.println("get create request");
          }
        }
```

then i send post request like this :

```
{"issue": {
    "project_id": 1,
    "subject": "Example"
  }
}
```

finally  I get this exception :

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "issue" (Class com.rakuten.tranp.api.bean.TestBean), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@783478b0; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.rakuten.tranp.api.bean.TestBean["issue"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1311)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1262)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:801)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:764)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:212)
    ... 28 more
```

how to solve this question, please help me,
Thank your every much ,
regurd.

Comment: are u using spring?

Comment: yes , i use spring in my module

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your `application.property` file and then try again:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
```

Comment: i don't have this file , how to set this property ?

Comment: is there any other config file, in which you have mentioned configurations

Answer (score 0):

The error stack trace is straightforward and fair enough to identify the problem:

> Unrecognized field "issue" (Class com.rakuten.tranp.api.bean.TestBean)

It means that you are trying to post a JSON with a property `ìssue`, this is what we can see in your JSON, which doesn't exist in your Java Bean so it causes this Exception because the property isn't recognized and can't be mapped.

**Solution:**

So you need to change your JSON to include only the inner properties of your `issue`object:

```
{
    "projectId": 1,
    "subject": "Example"
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you can't change your JSON then you need to have two POJO classes:

1. First one `Issue` with the two properties `projectId` and `subject`
   as you wrote in your `TestBean` class.
2. Second is `TestBean` that should only accept an object of type
   `Issue`.

Comment: sure , your are right , but json format must like that ,  how  to do

Comment: @wenbogu I edited my answer with the right solution.